# Making \xrightarrow longer but without using spaces

Tags: tables, amsmath, arrows

I have this table, and as you can see I make the last arrow longer with loads of spaces. Is there a better way to make it as long as the other `\plusarrow`s but at the same time with a centered text (only the equal sign)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\plusarrow}{$\xrightarrow{+\Delta V \%}$}
\newcommand{\bmin}{\textbf{--}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c l r c r}
        & \textbf{Ricavi} & 2000 & \plusarrow{} &
            \textbf{2140.00}\\
        \bmin{} & Costi operativi \dashuline{variabili} [660] & &
            \plusarrow{} & \textbf{706.20}\\
        & Acquisti materie prime & 150\\
        & Provvigioni passive & 180\\
        & Lavoro straordinario & 20\\
        & Lavorazioni esterne & 310\\
    \midrule
        = & \textbf{Margine di contribuzione} & 1340 & \plusarrow{} &
            \textbf{1433.80}\\
        \bmin{} & Costi operativi \dashuline{fissi} [860] & &
            $\xrightarrow{\ ~~=~~\ }$ & \textbf{860.00}\\ %% HERE
        & Lavoro ordinario & 420\\
        & Ammortamenti & 210\\
        & Affitti passivi & 90\\
        & Canoni di leasing & 140\\
    \midrule
    = & \textbf{Risultato operativo lordo} & 480 & & \textbf{573.80}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the current result:
[image: Table]

While it is perfectly fine, I don't like the hack that I used to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution using

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\phantom{+\Delta V \%}}
\newcommand{\equalarrow}{%
   $\vphantom{\xrightarrow{=}}%
    \smash{\xrightarrow[\foo]{=‌​}}%
   $}
```

Note that `\equalarrow` already contains `$ $` in its definition. Also, I added the @Heiko's suggestion to adjust the vertical space created by the invisible content.

Comment: It works perfectly! But why can't I use my `\plusarrow{}` command inside of phantom?

Comment: @rubik, I edited.

Comment: Because of the invisible contents below the arrow, the vertical spacing is increased accordingly. `\hphantom` is better than `\phantom` here.  The additional invisible depth can be entirely removed by `\smash`:  `\newcommand{\equalarrow}{$\vphantom{\xrightarrow{=}}\smash{\xrightarrow[\foo]{=}}$}`